# how to map a list to a column and create a new column

Tags: pandas, mapping

so I have a list of code like `code = ['1', '2', '3']`
and I need to map to a column account type which contains values like 1, 2, 3...

If the value is in the list then I like to have `cc` and if it is not in the list then that particular account type should have `non cc`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) combined with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['col'].isin(code), 'cc', 'non cc')
```

Example:

```
  col     new
0   0  non cc
1   1      cc
2   2      cc
3   3      cc
4   4  non cc
5   5  non cc
```

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']})
code = ['1', '2', '3']
```